# Can someone explain how this "request" code works?

Tags: python, request, bitcoin

I am using the following code to get BTC data from coinbase. I just copied this from a tutorial but I want to know how it actually works. Can someone explain step by step? Thank you

```py
import requests # imports the request library

url = "https://api.exchange.coinbase.com/products/BTC-USD/book?level=1" # provides the url from which data will be pulled

headers = {"Accept": "application/json"} # I don't understand the point of this line

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers) # I just don't understand the point of the 'header' part

print(response.text) # This just prints the result
```

This is the result of the above code:

```
{"bids":[["45890.49","0.02316146",1]],
 "asks":[["45896.07","0.03631374",1]],
 "sequence":35929645093,
 "auction_mode":false,
 "auction":null}
```

I understand all this data, just not how the code gets it

Comment: Well, you first. Please explain the code step by step until you don't know how something works.

Comment: https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/

Comment: Seems the *only* thing here is to understand that python code can call a web server, exactly as your browser does when you display a website. You go on Chrome to a website, the code go to a API (kind of website) , same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code sends a `GET` request to `https://api.exchange.coinbase.com/products/BTC-USD/book?level=1` with additional HTTP Headers:

```
Accept: application/json
```

This results in the webserver to send the result of your query in a JSON-Format, which you can access using `response.text`